# iOS pass the value instead of reference

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, pass-by-value

When executing the below block. My `friends_dict` NSMutableDictionary value changes as  `friend` changes. If I'm not wrong this is because the reference of the value in the dictionary is passed along to the `friend`. How can I pass the value instead of reference and prevent the dictionary from changing.

```
NSMutableArray *friendsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[friends_dict valueForKey:selectedFriendId]];
for (NSObject *object in [response objectForKey:@"friend_nearby"]){
        NSString *id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"id"]];
        NSString *spotValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"spot"]];
        for(int i = 0; i < [friendsArray count]; i++){
            FriendDataModel *friend  = [[FriendDataModel alloc] init];
            friend = [friendsArray objectAtIndex:i];
            if ([friend.friendId isEqualToString:id] && ![friend.spot isEqualToString:spotValue] ) {
                friend.spot = spotValue; //This is where the dictionary value changes
                [friendsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:friend];
                spotChanged = YES;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not mutate an array while enumerating it.

Comment: Pass a copy of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the array and pass in the copy.

```
NSArray *friendList = [friends_dict valueForKey:selectedFriendId];
NSMutableArray *friendsArray = [friendList mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Before "it doesn't work" comment, you need to make `FriendDataModel` to conform to `NSCopying`.

Comment: @A-Live Thanks for the heads up! I'm doing it ;)

Comment: @Zaph I'm pretty sure he needs a deep one.

Comment: In addition to this I also changed `friend = [friendsArray objectAtIndex:i];` to `friend = [[friendsArray objectAtIndex:i] copy];` and it worked!

Comment: @A-Live Yes, for what the OP is doing it looks like she will need a deep copy.

Comment: @A-Live Yes I needed to deep copy it. And I'm a she. Thanks for your help.